# Create javaScript variable in code behind of asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How do I register a Javascript variable on the server side (backend) and access it on the client side (Javascript file), without a hidden field, Literal, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)-Function from the Page's ClientScriptManager.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "initMyClientVariable", "var myClientVariable=null;", True)
```

**EDIT**: according to your new informations, that you want to register a client array, use ClientScriptManager's [RegisterArrayDeclaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerarraydeclaration.aspx) Method.

VB.Net example:

```
Dim myArrayValue As String = """1"", ""2"", ""text"""
Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("myClientArray", myArrayValue)
```

According to the new information in my comments that you need access to that variable from an external js-file: you should pass the js-array as argument to the function in the js-file. For example:

```
callFunctionInJsFile(checkBoxes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Information. I did the same way , but i stuct up with one more issue . That variable registered appears in <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var myClientVariable=System.String[];//]]>
</script> . (1) when i try to acceess that variable(myClientVariable) its throws message Object expected.How to access that variable to proceed further. (2) For myClientVariable i want to assign some variable in code behind , how can assign value .  Pls assist me

Comment: Ya i tried that Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("myClientArray", myArrayValue). But how to access that array in the Javascript file so that i can work on that array. Kindly help me out

Comment: You can access that array from client-side directly. View page-source in browser to see that the variable is available and intialized correctly.

Comment: Hi , i tried following Method : In Page_load() of Asp.net (C# Code)   String myArrayValue = "abc";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("myClientArray", myArrayValue);  But in the JavaScript Side : when it comes to CDATA Block like :::: <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var myClientArray =  new Array(abc);
//]]>
<                                                                 it throws Error : myClientArray is undefined.                                                          kindly help me to solve this issue . If possible quote me an example

Comment: Also suggest how to handle in Masterpages , AjaxUpdate panels (i m using both ). pls suggest me

Comment: I finaly Registered an array in the Server side(C#) and in JS (View Source i am able to see )<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var myClientArray =  new Array(#PdtMgmt#,#ZapPdtTest);
//]]>
</script> . When i try to access in some function :   function lookupValue()
    { 
var aErrors=myClientArray;     }  . Its giving error Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'myClientArray' is undefined . Please get me out of this problem . (I m using masterpages and Ajax panels is that becz of That) Plshelp me out

Comment: You have forgotten to double-quote the Array-Values in `new Array(#PdtMgmt#,#ZapPdtTest);`

Comment: I cant do anything in )<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var myClientArray = new Array(#PdtMgmt#,#ZapPdtTest); //]]> </script> block na. to Register arry in code behind ( Page Load Event ) i m using folloe=ing mwthod System.Text.StringBuilder sbScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sbScript.Append(",");
            sbScript.Append("abc");
            sbScript.Append(",");
            sbScript.Append("xyz");

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("checkBoxes", sbScript.ToString());

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("checkBoxes", "'cba','abc','xyz'",);` should work

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. But my Problem is when i try to access the array in some function in javascript file (.js) its giving error stating :"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'checkBoxes' is undefined" Is that becz of Master Pages, which i m using or becz of using .js file separately  (I m able to see <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var checkBoxes =  new Array('cba','abc','xyz');
//]]>
</script> , in the View Source but not able to accees). Kindly help me out

Comment: Why do you need to access from an external js-file a variable that belongs to a special page? But you can add the variable also in the Masterpage codebehind.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the following code in .aspx file ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var date1 = "<%: DateTime.Now %>";
    var date2 = "<%= DateTime.Now %>";
</script>

<%:  %> works under ASP.NET 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put a literal in the xml portion of the code and assign that literal some text:

```
myLiteral.Text = "<script language=\"javascript\">var myVar = 24;</script>";
```

This makes `myVar` globally available on the client side once it's rendered. You can also use the [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx) object to use Asp.Net to inject scripts and variables.

Answer (score 1):

First place an <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal> tag in the <head> of your .aspx file. 
Then in the server side code in your .aspx.cs file, do something like **Literal1.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var timer = 3600</script>"** and you've got yout javascript variable called timer.

That's it. Have fun!